# Same-table Tree Table Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, recursion, tree, common-table-expression

I've searched but found nothing that could help.

I have the following table in a SQL Server 2005 database:

```
Parent     Child             Value
----       --------          ---------
America    Mexico            8
America    Canada            1
Asia       Japan             5
Asia       Korea             7
Europe     Spain             0
Europe     Italy             2
Africa     Zimbabwe          1
Mexico     Baja California   0
America    USA               3
USA        California        1
USA        Texas             2
```

Parent and Child are Primary Key, value is not important (IMO). I would like to create a view that results in something like this:

```
Parent     Child             Value
----       --------          ---------
America    USA               3
USA        California        1
USA        Texas             2
```

I would search for America, and the result will give back every nested child there is, recursively, no matter how many it has, since I could include cities, localities, etc.

What I need is similar to what some call a BOM explosion.

Comment: Are those the three rows you want or are there a bunch of other rows that you left out?

Comment: I left out a bunch of rows, those three rows are the result set if I for example want all the children of America and USA

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
with cte as (
       select parent, child
       from t
       union all
       select cte.parent, t.child
       from cte join
            t
            on cte.child = t.parent
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where parent = 'America';
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28771) is a small SQL Fiddle example.